# Hibernate not looking up attribute value

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Using hibernate and I am having trouble saving an instance.

I have the following DB structure:

```
Item
 - id
 - attributeId
 - other stuff

Attribute
  - id
  - code
  - name
```

Assume the attribute table has entries like:

```
1  T Type1
2  R RType
3  G GType
```

Here are the annotations for that class:

```
Class Attribute {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE", updatable = false)
    protected String code;

    @Column(name = "NAME", updatable = false)
    protected String name;
}
```

So I want to be able to create a new Item class and give it a Attribute class with the code and name filled out.  Have hibernate look up the id for the attribute, and insert that id into the attributeId column of Item.

These are my annotations for Item:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
                generator = "item_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "item_seq", sequenceName = "ITEM_SEQ",
                   allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "ID")
protected long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ATTRIBUTE_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Attribute attribute;
```

How can I give the Item class a Attribute class, with the code and description filled out, and have it look up the id for the attribute and assign it to the Item?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the attribute id explicitly, Hibernate will do that for you. You just need to set an instance of `Attribute` (be it a new instance, or an existing one) to `Item` instance, and save that item. Something like this

```
Item item = new Item();
// if you want to use an existing attribute, fetch it from some DAO by id
Attribute att = session.get(Attribute.class, someId);
item.setAttribute(att);
// save item
session.save(item);
```

Comment: That is the key, I don't want to have to do a get.  I want to the lookup to be done when the save is occurring.

Comment: Ok, use `session.load()` instead of `session.get()`. It will just hold a reference to an entity without making a select to db.